# Kivy (Python) program crashing on Raspberry Pi (crashlog)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy

I have recently installed Kivy on a Raspberry Pi (with Raspbian system), following the instructions on the Kivy website.

I meant to test a program I wrote. It worked fine on my Linux Mint computer. However, on Raspbian it crashed with a weird error linking to one of Kivy's own functions.

Here's the terminal output:

```
$ python main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-01-10_6.txt
[INFO   ] Kivy v1.9.0-dev
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23) 
[GCC 4.6.3]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 2.0>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Broadcom>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <VideoCore IV HW>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event1
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event1>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event2
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event2>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <CHESEN USB Keyboard>
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <CHESEN USB Keyboard>
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <PixArt USB Optical Mouse>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 145, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 825, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 484, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 77, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 72, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 324, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 483, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 615, in _process_events
     event.tick(self._last_tick, remove)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 374, in tick
     ret = callback(self._dt)
 TypeError: create_window() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Just as a wild guess, to see how it will work, I tried to edit Kivy's "create_window()" function, located inside "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", by adding an optional argument to its declaration. Running my program again produced some sort of segmentation error instead, and so I stopped messing with Kivy's code...

Any idea how to fix the error hinted in this log? (MainApp().run() is the very beginning of my program, and everything else is Kivy functions, apparently called automatically by this command)

Comment: Did you follow [the official instructions](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-rpi.html) and updated cython?

Comment: Yes, I installed Cython following those particular instructions, and not from repository. For some reason Cython installation took a very long time, so before I had the patience to sit through it, I tried running Kivy's build command anyway - it refused to build without Cython installed. Later, with Cython installed, it built just fine.

Comment: [Some people reported](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/kivy-users/DgJvNWPDIyw/B9e6Cx8o7bEJ) that upgrading python to 2.7.8 would work.

Comment: Yes, this might be the case - my current Python is 2.7.3
On that note, what's the best way to upgrade it? I tried building 2.7.9 from source on Raspberry, but running "./configuration" said that the C compiler couldn't build executables (even though I had gcc installed and updated to version 4.7). Using apt-get (even after update/upgrade) doesn't work too, it says Python is already the newest version (I checked, it's still 2.7.3)
Could it be easier to just install a development version of Raspbian, that has Python 2.7.8 by default? (can't remember the name of that Raspbian distribution...)

Comment: Sure, you can move to jessie (testing) or just get the python package and its dependencies.

Comment: I was finally able to upgrade Raspbian to Testing packages, but didn't finish Kivy installation (seems like there was some bug in the development source at that moment, I figured).
Instead I tried installing the KivyPie system image for Raspberry. Kivy works from the start in it, though I've noticed that Kivy "Config.set" functions for setting up screen resolution aren't working for some reason... Other than that, Kivy runs fine. The graphics are really smooth for my purposes, too.

Answer (score 5):

I was experiencing the same error, with the same scenario - my program runs fine on a Windows machine, yet crashes with the same error on RPi. In my case, I am running an updated Python version - 2.7.9.

It appears that the *Window.size* assignment is the source of the crash:

```
class MainApp(App):
  def build(self):
    Window.size = (1280,800)     # <---- Crashes on RPi
```

Removing this assignment fixed the program.

Comment: I didn't have that statement in my program, but after seeing your message I found that the line that was working for me in Windows but crashing things on my Raspberry Pi was Window.fullscreen = "auto"